# Toggle class on link click

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, toggle

I'm trying to toggle a class for a link when it is clicked so it either shows plus to expand or minus to reduce but I can't get it working.

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$(".viewdetails").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('viewdetailsoff');
    $(this).parents("tr").next().toggle();
    return false;
 })
```

My initial link

```
<a class="viewdetails" title="View History" href="">History</a>
```

Comment: is the click event being triggered? (try adding "alert('triggered');" as the first line in the click function.)

Comment: You should post some more HTML context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the image that isn't working, make sure `.viewdetailsoff` is defined **after** `.viewdetails` in the CSS, like this:

```
.viewdetails {
   background-image: url(minus.jpg);
}

.viewdetailsoff {
   background-image: url(plus.jpg);
}
```

Regardless of class order on the element itself, e.g. it'll be `class="viewdetails viewdetailsoff"`, the order in the CSS is what determines which one wins.  Or, you could toggle *both* classes, effectively swapping them using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('viewdetails viewdetailsoff');
```